# How to Iterate through a conversation in Oulook?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

Am building a outlook addin that will set category to an email , I have a special scenario where in If i match a subject i am looking for , i need the entire conversation category to be set i.e. the entire thread needs to be set to a category , i have been using Conversation object but in vain ,
can anybody help me with this.